# Component CSS Disappears from Components During App Bootsrapping With Preboot

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

My beautiful server-side rendered Angular 5 application (using Universal with a node express.js server) is having problems with styling during the bootstrap (preboot) phase. The global CSS stylesheet seems to be fine, but the component-specific styles disappear once bootstrapping begins.

**Example:**

Component styling with javascript disabled (pure html and css from the server):
[image: javascript disabled]

Component styling with javascript enabled and before app starts bootstrapping (still fine, still pure html and css from the server):
[image: before bootstrapping]

Component styling during bootstrapping transition phase (terrible because the component specific styles are gone. `h1[_ngcontent-c25]` is no longer there):
[image]

Component styling after app bootstrapping is completely finished (`h1[_ngcontent-c25]` is back):
[image]

What is going on here and how do I fix it?

**For reference**

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
],
imports: [
    // BrowserModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'universal' }),
    PrebootModule.withConfig({ appRoot: 'app-root' }),
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    CoreModule, // this is where everything else is
    AppRoutingModule,
],
bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Versions:

```
Angular: 5.0.3
Angular-cli: 1.5.0
"preboot": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.5",
"@nguniversal/common": "5.0.0-beta.5",
"express": "^4.16.2",
```

UPDATE:

Example repo with same problem from another developer: https://github.com/angular/preboot/issues/58

Comment: Can you link to an example repo?

Comment: @AdamP I just added a link to preboot issue with example repo.

Comment: Since your issue was fixed in that issue, can you close this question/post the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things solved the problem for me:

1. Add `{initialNavigation: 'enabled'}` to config param of RouterModule.forRoot import.

like this:

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     RouterModule.forRoot( routes, { initialNavigation: 'enabled' } )
   ],
   ...
```

2. Upgrade to latest version of preboot (`6.0.0-beta.1`)

Comment: trying to understand what initialNavigation does different than normal lazy routes loading.