# Preboot non-working client app - Angular 6 universal

Tags: angular, universal

I'm having issues when using **preboot** on an **angular 6** app.

Basically, the client app is not working at all, the client-specific **scripts don't work** (like scroll listeners, HTTP calls, etc., I think there's actually no controllers), the **styles are gone** (same issue as: [Component CSS Disappears from Components During App Bootsrapping With Preboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701349/component-css-disappears-from-components-during-app-bootsrapping-with-preboot))

The server app works fine (it's still present in the DOM but with a display:none see image link)
[DOM Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztoDO.png)

Has anyone had the same issue? I get no error whatsoever (both on the browser console or in the server console), so I don't know what's happening at all.

**PS**: I solved the styling issue with this answer: https://github.com/angular/preboot/issues/75#issuecomment-421266570